# Where is my mistake in finding this lim ? $\lim\limits_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}\frac{|y|}{x^{2}}~e ^{-\frac{|y|}{x^{2}}}$

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus

Im going to find the mistake in this two solutions :

Question $\to $ find :

$$\Omega =\lim\limits_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}\frac{|y|}{x^{2}}~e ^{-\frac{|y|}{x^{2}}}$$

**The first suggested solution**

Let prove does not exist lim :

$•\color{red}{y=x^{2}}$ then :

$$\Omega =\lim\limits_{(x,x^{2})\to (0,0)}\frac{|x^{2}|}{x^{2}}~e ^{-\frac{|x^{2}|}{x^{2}}}$$

$$=\lim\limits_{(x,x^{2})\to (0,0)}e ^{-\frac{x^{2}}{x^{2}}}=\color{green}{\frac{1}{e}}$$

$•\color{red}{y=x}$ then :

$$\Omega =\lim\limits_{(x,x)\to (0,0)}\frac{|x|}{x^{2}}~e ^{-\frac{|x|}{x^{2}}}$$

$$\Omega =\lim\limits_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}\frac{1}{|x|}~e ^{-\frac{1}{|x|}}$$
$$=\lim\limits_{t\to +\infty}te^{-t}=\color{green}{0}$$
 This mean that : does not exist lim!

**The second suggested solution**

Using the polar coordinates, we find:

$$x=r\cos \theta , y=r\sin \theta $$

So :

$$\Omega =\lim\limits_{r\to 0}\frac{|\sin \theta |}{r\cos^{2} \theta }e^{-\frac{|\sin \theta |}{r\cos^{2} \theta }}$$

$$=\lim\limits_{t\to +\infty}te^{-t}=\color{red}{0}$$

---

I am waiting for your explanation, comments and advice, I will be happy if i see other ways!

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

The first suggested solution is correct.

It is wrong to say that $\frac {|sin \theta | }{ r\cos^{2} \theta} \to \infty$ as $ r \to 0$.  What happens when $\sin \theta =0$?

Answer (score 0):

Assume you have to calculate
$$
\mathop {\lim }\limits_{\left( {x,y} \right) \to \left( {0,0} \right)} f\left( {x,y} \right)
$$
and you want to use the trigonometrical substitution
$$x=r\cos \theta$$
$$y=r \sin \theta$$
Assume that 
$$
\mathop {\lim }\limits_{r \to 0} f\left( {r\cos \theta ,r\sin \theta } \right) = L
$$
Then it is true that
$$
\mathop {\lim }\limits_{\left( {x,y} \right) \to \left( {0,0} \right)} f\left( {x,y} \right) = L
$$
if and only if $L$ is independent from $\theta$.

Answer (score 0):

Different paths can be interpreted  in polar form via different angles through which we approach the limit. The function behaves differently  when you approach the origin through two different lines  $\theta=0$  and $\theta=\pi/2$ . Thus even in your polar approch also, conclusion would be the same.